# Facing issue with catalogsearch_query table when using Magento search

Tags: magento-1, search-terms

I have a Magento 1.4.1.1 setup on production server. When we search any term on the site it should be stored in the *catalogsearch_query* table.

But for me some search terms are not being saved in this table.

Similar issue was on *local system* with production DB but when I *truncated* this table everything started working fine.

On production I did full re-indexing, checked for the class overrides and custom modules also but nothing helped.

So is there any way to fix this table ***without truncating and loosing*** the search terms?

I know there there is foreign key dependency on *catalogsearch_result* table also, with *query_id* field.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this yet?

Comment: @ArjenMiedema I have fixed it clearing the table and re importing the search terms.

Answer (score 4):

As the topic starter stated in his comment, the fix for this was to backup the search terms, then truncate the table and reimport the search terms again.